# Trying to keep ArrayList Immutable

Tags: java, list, mutable

So I have a class named Album which contains a static ArrayList named 'listOfAllAlbumsCreated'.

```
   public class Album {
    private static ArrayList<Album> listOfAllAlbumsCreated= new ArrayList<>();

           public Album(String albumTitle) {
                this.albumTitle = albumTitle;
                listOfAllAlbumsCreated.add(this);

    }


public static ArrayList<Album> getListOfAllAlbumsCreated() {
        return listOfAllAlbumsCreated;
    }// I only want PlayList Class to Access this!

}
```

Basically, whenever an Album object is created, 'listOfAllAlbumsCreated' adds that object to it. Then, I created a PlayList Class which should have access to all albums created-  by getting the 'listOfAllAlbumsCreated' and assigning another ArrayList to it.

```
 public class PlayList {
    private static ArrayList<Album> allExistingAlbums = Album.getListOfAllAlbumsCreated();

 public PlayList(String playListName) {
        this.playListName = playListName;
    }

}
```

This, however, allows anyone in other classes to just call the Album.getListOfAllAlbumsCreated and possibly change the content of all albums created which i obviously don't want to. So how can i keep listOfAllAlbumsCreated safe; i.e. only accessible to my PlayList class?

Thanks!

Comment: You can use [`Collections.unmodifiableList(...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#unmodifiableList-java.util.List-) to return an unmodifiable view of your `List`. But keep in mind that the *elements* in the list are still mutable (except you designed your `Album` as immutable).

Comment: I see your point but I'm still wondering if I can make the listOfAllAlbumsCreated accessible to only Playlist class or anything similar- if possible in java. Any thoughts?

Comment: Or you can just return shallow copy of your list in `Album.getListOfAllAlbumsCreated()`  by using a constructor `new ArrayList<Album>(listOfAllAlbumsCreated)`. This way you'll get a new 
unique list every time you call the getter, but the objects themselves will still be modifiable.

Comment: @SamiSawani you can set the method to [the default modifier or `protected`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html) (granting access to classes in the same packe or deriving classes and classes in the same package, respectively). Would this satisfy your needs?

Comment: Appreciate this but sorry it wouldn't help @Turing85. Even, the unmodifiableList solution won't work coz i can still change the elements like you said. Ideally, I want to keep the listOfAllAlbumsCreated accessible to only Playlist so that nothing can access it to alter it in the first place!

Comment: the long way would be to change the basic design on my part but that would take a lot of time! In other words, I want to keep the Album class, and then PlayList class separate from each other so that each can do its part without interfering or putting either one as an inner class inside the other

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. There are two options that come to my mind.

**Option 1: limit access through access modifiers.**

The [Oracle tutorial on access control](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html) has a neat table overview of what the different access modifiers do (Table generate with [Senseful](https://senseful.github.io/text-table/)):

```
╔═════════════╦═══════╦═════════╦══════════╦═══════╗
║  Modifier   ║ Class ║ Package ║ Subclass ║ World ║
╠═════════════╬═══════╬═════════╬══════════╬═══════╣
║ public      ║ Y     ║ Y       ║ Y        ║ Y     ║
║ protected   ║ Y     ║ Y       ║ Y        ║ N     ║
║ no modifier ║ Y     ║ Y       ║ N        ║ N     ║
║ private     ║ Y     ║ N       ║ N        ║ N     ║
╚═════════════╩═══════╩═════════╩══════════╩═══════╝
```

From your description, the `private` modifier (granting access only from within the current class), the `no modifier` (granting access only from within the current class and classes in the same package) or the `protected` modifier (granting acces from within the current class, classes in the same package and deriving classes) might be what you are looking for. The example shows it with no modifier.

```
static ArrayList<Album> getListOfAllAlbumsCreated() {
    return listOfAllAlbumsCreated;
}
```

**Option 2: Return an unmodifiable view of your list.**

To return an unmodifiable view of your `List` throung [`Collections.unmodifiableList(...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#unmodifiableList-java.util.List-). Your code would then look like this:

```
public static ArrayList<Album> getListOfAllAlbumsCreated() {
    return Collections.unmodifiableList(listOfAllAlbumsCreated);
}
```

Two words of warning regarding the unmodifiable list:

- changes made to the original `List` after you called `getListOfallAlbumsCreated()` will not be reflected in the unmodifiable view. The unmodifiable view is only a view of the list at the point in time you created the unmodifiable view.
- While the returned `List` is unmodifiable, the entries within the `List` are not. Java has no concept of `const` objects, like C++ has. To achieve true immutability, you need to desing your `Album` class as immutable. In the future, we will most probably have [value types](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/valhalla/), which will ease the implementation of immutables, coupled with some neat performance benefits.

---

Two design remarks:

- What you are doing is basically re-create the Java-equivalent to a memory leak. An instace of `Album` will not be garbage-collected unless you also remove it from `listOfAllAlbumsCreated`. This may or may not be what you want. What you can do is use [`WeakReference`s](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/ref/WeakReference.html), in order to allow garbage-collection of objects, if only `WeakReference`s to this object exist. You would change `listOfAllAlbumsCreated` to `List<WeakReference<Album>>`. This, in return, can lead to situations where some references return `null` when you call `get()` on them. You could try to solve this by overriding the `finalize()` method, but this is highly discouraged.
- If you already have some kind of bookkeeping for your `Album`s, you could implement the [Factory Method Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) or the [Builder Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern) in order to prevent creation of duplicates. For a more complete example of this, you may want to take a look at the implementation of [`Integer.valueOf(int value)`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/Integer.java#Integer.valueOf%28int%29).

Answer (score 1):

I think you're conflating some concepts here.

Something being "immutable" means it cannot be changed once created. It seems that you don't want your ArrayList to be immutable - just protected as to who exactly can access it.

To protect who can access your data (or call your methods), you should change its [access modifiers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html) - one of either `public`, `protected`, `package-private`, or `private`.

As of right now, no one can actually change the contents of the `listOfAllAlbumsCreated` ArrayList except for the Album class, because the variable is private and there doesn't seem to be any method that changes its contents. The `getListOfAllAlbumsCreated` is public, meaning any class can call this method and see what's inside your ArrayList.

If you only want Playlist to be able to call this method, you'll need to refactor a bit (unless Playlist will be the only other class in your package...which is unlikely). However, there doesn't seem to be a relationship between Album and Playlist that makes sense - making Playlist a subclass of Album doesn't seem like a sound solution. I would instead figure out if the `listOfAllAlbumsCreated` really needs to be inside the Album class. It seems kind of strange for an Album to know about all of the other Albums that exist; this is probably not good design. I would either store the ArrayList of albums in another class (perhaps the Playlist class since you want to restrict access to *only* this class), or maybe create an AlbumList class.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can think of is to make `Playlist` static inner class of `Album`, lose the getter and access `listOfAllAlbumsCreated` inside `Playlist` alone:

```
public class Album {
    private static ArrayList<Album> listOfAllAlbumsCreated= new ArrayList<>();

    public Album(String albumTitle) {
        this.albumTitle = albumTitle;
        listOfAllAlbumsCreated.add(this);
    }

    public static class PlayList {

        public PlayList(String playListName) {
            this.playListName = playListName;
        }

        public someMethod() {
            listOfAllAlbumsCreated.get(0);
        }
    }
}
```

This is probably not a good solution, because it doesn't really make sense for `Playlist` to be declared inside `Album` class, but it does do exactly what you want.